# Training a Bernoulli model using probabilities as inputs

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, stan

I'm using two methods to train a Bernoulli model, and am trying to understand why they are not yielding similar results. For both methods, I have a length $N$ array of probabilities $\{\hat{y}^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^{N}$, and I want to estimate the distribution of a length $N$ array of parameters $\{\theta^{(n)}\}_{n=1}^{N}$. In method (1), for each $\hat{y}^{(n)}$, I sample $M$ times from a Bernoulli distribution with probability $\hat{y}^{(n)}$, and use the resulting binary data as the input to my model. In method (2), I use $\hat{y}^{(n)}$ directly by incrementing the log joint density using the following update rule:

$
 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
  \log p(\mathbf{y} \mid \boldsymbol{\theta}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log p(y^{(n)} \mid \theta^{(n)})\\
  &\approx \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^{M} \log p(y^{(n)}_m \mid \theta^{(n)})\\
  &\approx \sum_{n=1}^{N} E_{y^{(n)}_m}[\log p(y^{(n)}_m \mid \theta^{(n)})]\\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} E_{y^{(n)}_m}\left[\log({\theta^{(n)}}^{y^{(n)}_m} \cdot (1 - \theta^{(n)})^{1 - y^{(n)}_m})\right]\\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} E_{y^{(n)}_m}\left[y^{(n)}_m \log(\theta^{(n)}) +  (1 - y^{(n)}_m) \log(1 - \theta^{(n)})\right]\\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \Pr(y^{(n)}_m = 1) \log(\theta^{(n)}) + \Pr(y^{(n)}_m = 0) \log(1 - \theta^{(n)})\\
  &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \hat{y}^{(n)} \log(\theta^{(n)}) + (1 - \hat{y}^{(n)}) \log(1 - \theta^{(n)})
  \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
$

I'm using Stan, where you specify the log joint density incrementally using each data point. Pseudocode for these two methods looks like this:

[image: Stan psuedocode]

I expect methods (1) and (2) to yield similar estimates for $\theta$ for large $M$, but I'm finding this to not be the case. I've reproduced this issue on a small toy problem using Stan, here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pystan

def get_theta_mean(fit):
    samples = fit.extract()
    theta = np.moveaxis(samples['theta'], 0, -1)
    return theta.mean(axis=1)

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
N = 100
probs = rng.uniform(0, 1, N)

binary_model = '''
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    int<lower=0> M;
    int<lower=0, upper=1> y[M, N];
}
parameters {
    real<lower=0, upper=1> theta[N];
}
model {
    for (m in 1:M) {
        y[m] ~ bernoulli(theta);
    }
}
'''
binary_sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=binary_model)

M_list = [10, 100, 1000]
theta_means = {}

for M in M_list:
    y = np.full((M, N), np.nan)
    for m in range(M):
        for n in range(N):
            y[m, n] = rng.binomial(1, probs[n])
    y = y.astype(int)

    binary_fit = binary_sm.sampling(
        data={'N': N, 
              'M': M, 
              'y': y})

    theta_means[M] = get_theta_mean(binary_fit)

prob_model = '''
data {
    int<lower=0> N;
    real<lower=0, upper=1> yhat[N];
}
parameters {
    real<lower=0, upper=1> theta[N];
}
model {
    for (n in 1:N) {
        target += lmultiply(yhat[n], theta[n]) + lmultiply(1 - yhat[n], 1 - theta[n]);
    }
}
'''
prob_sm = pystan.StanModel(model_code=prob_model)
prob_fit = prob_sm.sampling(
    data={'N': N,
          'yhat': probs})

prob_theta_mean = get_theta_mean(prob_fit)

for M, theta_mean in theta_means.items():
    plt.scatter(theta_mean, probs, label=f'Method (1), M={M}')
plt.scatter(prob_theta_mean, probs, label='Method (2)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel(r'$E[\theta]$')
plt.ylabel('Probability')
plt.legend()
```

Here is a scatterplot of the results I get on the toy problem. (1) is supposed to better approximate (2) as $M$ is increased, eventually converging to $E[\theta^{(n)}] = \hat{y}^{(n)}$. (1) seems to follow this, but (2) is significantly off.

[image: Stan output]

UPDATE:

I realized there is an error in line one of my derivation above, and that method (2) actually represents

$
 \begin{equation*}
   \begin{split}
   \log p(\vec{y} \mid \theta) &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log p(y^{(n)} \mid \theta^{(n)})\\
   &\approx \sum_{n=1}^{N} \log\left(\frac{1}{M} \sum_{m=1}^{M}  p(y^{(n)}_m \mid \theta^{(n)})\right)
   \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
$

I changed method (1) to reflect this, and now my results between method (1) and (2) are consistent, and neither of them satisfy $E[\theta \mid D] \approx \hat{y}$.

[image: corrected]

Comment: Hi. Please give more detail when you say you're ``finding this to not be the case''. What is your choice of $M$? Are you sharing information between each value of $\theta$ with a prior? If so what is that prior? I note also from step (1) in your pseudo code that you're not dividing by M at each increment. It seems like you should be.

Comment: @psboonstra I've attached a plot that shows the results of estimating $\theta$ using these two methods for various values of $M$. I am using a flat prior for $\theta$. I agree that the log densities are off by a constant amount based on there being $M$ times more data points in (1), but I wasn't sure whether this is a problem since (1) appears to recover $\theta$ more accurately for larger $M$ without any adjustments. (2) is supposed to be like (1) with $M = \inf$, but seems to be off systematically.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I see now that failing to scale by M will artificially decrease your uncertainty intervals, since it is tantamount to making up data, but it will not impact your point estimates. Your plot shows posterior means (I believe) only. Second, according to your plot, the problem is with Method 2, or how it is coded. You are using a [continuous Bernoulli model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Bernoulli_distribution), which is fine but a bit of an usual model for the data. I suggest to limit to one datapoint only for computational efficiency, and share the actual STAN model block

Comment: @psboonstra That's correct, the x-axis is the posterior mean. I added the code, including the Stan model block. binary_model is method (1), and prob_model corresponds to method (2). I tried running this code for small N, and I find it a bit difficult to visualize the issue this way, since the estimates for (2) seem correct for probabilities close to 0.5. I also tried modifying (2) to incorporate the $C(\lambda)$ constant in the continuous Bernoulli pdf that you shared. This seems to bring method (2) slightly closer to (1), but it's still not similar.

Comment: I actually think your first approximation was fine: for the continuous Bernoulli distribution, the log-density evaluates to $x\log(\theta) + (1-x) \log(1-\theta)$, and for the discrete Bernoulli distribution, the average of $M$ log-densities evaluates to $(1/M)\sum_m [x_m\log(\theta) + (1-x_m) \log(1-\theta)] = \bar x_M\log(\theta) + (1-\bar x_M) \log(1-\theta)$, $\bar x_M$ will approach $x$ in probability. As I argue in my answer, the issue is that you need to scale by $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** My original answer below applies to your original approximation. With respect to your modified approximation, which is different but also a sensible approximation, the issue of scaling by $M$ or not doesn't matter anymore, because then it just becomes a constant shift in the log-posterior (you are essentially deciding whether to add a constant $-\log (M)$). The results, which are the same between Method 1 and Method 2, don't match your intuition because of a shrinkage effect, which I discuss below.

**Original answer**

Method (2) is giving the expected results; Method (1) is coded incorrectly because it is not scaled by $M$. If you scale each added increment to the log-posterior by $M$, then you will get similar results for large $M$. In more detail:

Method (2) is using a model based upon the [continuous Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_Bernoulli_distribution). The posterior means you are finding seem to be correct; the issue is that there is very little data and so the results are largely prior-driven. For example, I ran an adapted version of your code for $N=1$ and $\hat y=0.25$. Here is a histogram estimating the posterior distribution of $\theta$, with a red line indicating the value $\hat y = 0.25$:

[image: method 2, posterior distribution]

The posterior mean of $\theta$ is a shrinkage estimator of the observed data $\hat y = 0.25$ and the prior mean 0.5 (things look 'correct' in that case when you have $\hat y = 0.5$ because the data are exactly equal to the prior mean). But the mode of the distribution is approximately at the place you would expect.

As your mathematical derivation suggests, Method (1) should yield approximately equal inferences for large enough $M$. However, by not scaling by $M$, you are artificially creating a great deal of data, which is having the effect of overwhelming the prior (In a comment, I suggested this shouldn't affect point estimates, but I misspoke). See below for two posterior histograms corresponding to Method (1) using $M = 500$, one which properly scales by $M$ and another which does not $M$. You'll observe that the lack of scaling by $M$ creates an extremely tight, and inappropriately confident, distribution around the observed data.

[image: method 1, correct, posterior distribution]

[image: method 1, incorrect, posterior distribution]

Comment: Thank you, so it turns out that (2) was actually working as intended, but my intuition was wrong. I'll need to rethink some of my choices, such as my priors.